# pip install treq failing

Tags: python, http, twisted, pip

According to http://treq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, treq can be installed using pip, however it is failing. I can install treq using the tar file, but I am wondering why this is failing since http://pypi.python.org/simple/treq/ has 0.1.0 and 0.2.0.

```
$ sudo pip install treq
Downloading/unpacking treq
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement treq
No distributions at all found for treq
Storing complete log in <cut>.pip/pip.log
$ pip search treq
megrok.strictrequire      - Checks that all grokked "view-like" components
                            require a permission.
streql                    - Constant-time string comparison
trequests                 - A Tornado async HTTP/HTTPS client adaptor for
                            python-requests
treq                      - A requests-like API built on top of twisted.web's
                            Agent
repoze.bfg.restrequest    - a REST aware Request for implementing RESTful
                            applications with repoze.bfg

$
```

Just tried to install from tarfile and it can't find twisted either so wondering if there's basic issue with pip...

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
<snip>
Extracting treq-0.2.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding treq 0.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/treq-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for treq==0.2.0
Searching for Twisted>=12.1.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/: timed out -- Some packages      may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/: timed out -- Some packages     may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'Twisted' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for Twisted>=12.1.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('Twisted>=12.1.0')
$
```

Comment: For what it's worth: don't ever do `sudo pip install`.  Either use something that will let you install stuff into a place outside the system, like `virtualenv` or `pip install --user`, or use something that's designed to integrate with your system, like `pypi-install`.

Comment: Thanks for the feed-back. I tried pypi-install treq and that didn't work either.

Comment: Works just fine for me. Have you made sure no firewall/antivirus is blocking it?

Comment: Thanks, yes this seems to be the issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message reads:

> `Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/: timed out -- Some packages      may not be found!`

Did you check for a firewall blocking access to PyPI?

Comment: Good point, I didn't even think about that since I can access http://pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/ from my PC's browser. But doing wget from the node on which I am trying to install fails, so it does seem to be firewall related.

Comment: Yes it was a firewall issue. Setting https_proxy etc fixed the issue.